# Redirect in OpenCart

Tags: php, redirect, header, opencart, opencart2.x

Hi i have custom controller in admin page, and i want to redirect after some function is done. Here is my code:

```
public function save(){
    //some operations
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
    header("Location: ".htmlentities ($this->url->link('sale/order', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] .  '', 'SSL')));
}
```

as the result i see this in browser:

```
http://mystore/admin/index.php?route=sale/order&amp;amp;token=jYOWKAUGO3Xx20OcoRK00N3CFHqJJato
```

Instead of:

```
http://mystore/admin/index.php?route=sale/order&token=jYOWKAUGO3Xx20OcoRK00N3CFHqJJato
```

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenCart has a built in redirect function as part of the `response` library.

`$this->response->redirect('your url goes here', 'http status code goes here');`

Comment: for OpenCart 1.x you need to use 
`$this->redirect()`